# load a (xml) file from the classpath in a spring web app

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I'd like to take a xml file from my classpath to unmarshal it and use it for testing purposes.
My problem is to get it as an InputStream.
I wrote these lines but I always get a null result.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/testing/"+ COMPLETE_DOCUMENT + ".xml");
```

of course the path you see in the method argument is the one to my file.
I tried several combinations:

```
WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/testing/
classpath:testing/
classpath*:testing/
```

but I always get the InputStream = null.

I even tried to switch to

```
 ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(...)
```

but nothing happens. I suppose the path to the resource is somehow wrong, but I can't figure out where. From my servlet.xml I use some resource in the classpath configuring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer or Jaxb2Marshaller just with the syntax

```
"classpath:folder/file.xsd"
```

and it works perfectly. The folder I want to load my xml from is a sibling of the one in the example above.
What am I missing?

**EDIT :**
I try to follow the spring ClassPathResource helper class approach and I get a strange behaviour: as I said before I already have some resources loaded from the classpath by some spring beans at the startup. If I use the path to such resources in the code suggested by dardo in as follows:

```
ClassPathResource cpr = new ClassPathResource("xmlschemas/lrinode.xsd");
InputStream is = cpr.getInputStream();
```

I Still get a `FileNotFound Exception`!
Of course `"xmlschemas/lrinode.xsd"` is a xsd I load at the startup successfully. It doesn't work even if I use the full path to the resource, starting from the root of the application.

I'm starting to think I'm missing something trivial.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Spring provides a helper class named ClassPathResource

So something like:

```
ClassPathResource cpr = new ClassPathResource("folder/file.xsd");
InputStream is = cpr.getInputStream();
```

Should work, hope this helps!

Link to API Doc:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html

**Sidenote**

Also, if you're using it for testing purposes, might want to wire a bean mapped to the xsd.

Might want to look into a JAXB marshaller

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html#oxm-jaxb2-xsd

Comment: thanks, I'm interested in this helper class. I tried your solution but I still get
    `"java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [testing/sample_complete_document.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist"`   
exception. The file name is the actual name to the file in my classpath.
PS. I already use JAXB2 ^__^

Comment: Whats the full path if the xml document

Comment: the fullpath of the xml document is the following: `/VirtualResource2/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/testing/sample_complete_document.xml`. Of Course "VirtualResource2" is the name of my web application.

Comment: What is the path before you compile i should have asked, if its under the web-inf folder before you compile it isnt visible to the classpath

Comment: I tried to move my xml resource right on the side of the invoking class. Now they are sibling but I can't reach it anyway. It seems so weird. I'm starting to ask mysepf if my project is somehow not properly configured. For example, I'm using maven and I made an update of the project configuration (which changed some property of my project). Can it be somehow related to my problem?

Comment: If you are using maven, place it in src/main/resources/test.xml then it would be new classpathresource("test.xml")

Comment: ok, it seems we have an happy ending. Thank you very much! Finally the InputStream doesn't throw a FileNotFound exception! It seems my problem is the configuration of my maven project. There are some things I don't grasp anyway. If the maven project structure is so strict, why spring is able to load resources which aren't in the `main/resources` folder (basically my fault was to think: spring can, so why can't I?)? I mean the xml s chema loaded by jaxb2 and the properties file loaded by the placeHolderConfigurer.

Comment: If you are talking about mvc:resources think of them as more of a servlet to serve up static resources such as images.

Answer (score 3):

You need a combination you didn't try:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testing/"+ COMPLETE_DOCUMENT + ".xml");
```

The `WebContent/WEB-INF/classes` directory should already be on the classpath.

The `classpath:` syntax only works if you're using Spring's `ResourceLoader` abstraction, which you aren't. Your usage of `classpath:folder/file.xsd` in your `servlet.xml` woprks because Spring's passing it through a `ServletContextResourceLoader`, which resolves `classpath:` automatically.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, now the mist is clearing. Unluckly neither the solution you suggest works in my project. I suppose that the "classes" directory is in the classpath since it is located by the "classpath:" syntax working for the spring context, right? Uh... ok, I admit it. I'm not sure of what a classpath exaclty is. Very embarassing to say. I assume it is everything I can see from the root of my eclipse project in the package explorer. I know it is a variable, but I think eclipse would manage it automatically...

Comment: @maVVamaldo: Make sure you include the leading slash in the path. I added that a few seconds after my initial answer.

Comment: for the sake of completeness, this is the exact fragment of code I tried.
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testing/"+ COMPLETE_DOCUMENT + ".xml");

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Class.getResourceAsStream()` with resource name without leading slash, it assumes you are requesting resource relative to a current package (i.e. package of the caller class). To make it an absolute resource path you need to add leading slash to resource name, e.g. in your case `"/testing/"+ COMPLETE_DOCUMENT + ".xml"`